# influxdb count distinct field

Tags: distinct, grafana, influxdb

My table is a follow;

```
names
1.name
1.name
1.name
2.name
2.name
3.name
```

The result I want to get is as follows;

```
name    count
1.name  3
2.name  2
3.name  1
```

My request is

```
select distinct(name) from names where name=! /.*name*/ group by name
```

or

```
select count(distinct(name)) from names where name=! /.*name*/ group by name
```

My response

```
1.name
2.name
3.name
```

or

```
count 3
```

Thank for help

Answer (score -1):

You will need to select a field in the query and count the field names in the query

Assuming that there is a field called `field` is available in the measurement,

`select count(field1) from names where group by name` should work.

I'm not sure why `name=! /.*name*/`  where clause is added to the query.

Comment: Dear robert, query with influxdb and running

Comment: @phoemis glad it worked for you. Could please mark the answer as accepted?

Comment: no no, name=! /.*name*/ this method work for me :), this query select count(field1) from names where group by name me send two query select count(distinct(name)) from names where name=! /.*name*/ group by name